# How to create a Sci Fi antagonist in fantasy RPG?

Tags: the-dark-eye

I really enjoyed the [replicators of Stargate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replicator_(Stargate)) and I want to include them as long-term enemies in my created adventures. My challenge: I am playing The Dark Eye, which is a fantasy setting RPG.
How do I magically explain their skills for replication?

How can I make them 'flavorful'?  Maybe instead of robotic bugs they're magically created and 'sand bugs'?  Is there a "best practices" for porting Sci Fi creatures like that into The Dark Eye?

Comment: Welcome! You can take the [tour] as an introduction to the site and check the [help] if you need further guidance. Good luck and happy gaming!

Comment: Maybe you should rephares your questions like this: `What entetys/creatures in The Dark Eye would fit the properteries of replicators`. And then list the properties you think are important. Answers to this questions should not be opinon based, sice you have properties that can be (more or less) objectivly checked in the context of TDE. But since I'm not put this on hold, I can't garantee you that.

Comment: Note that in the history of TDE there had been canon SciFi - which was de-canonized. There had been a goddang Spaceship!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be demons I guess.

A shape shifting mass that absorb other material to grow. Split itself up to multiple entetys that share a common mind.

I guess Lolgrimoth would be a good domain. Always changing fits pretty good I think.

Another approach would be some bug like demons that I think where in the south-east. They were an ancient demon consisting of many bugs. They were used in the scorpion wars and destroyed the sultanate Gorien [Wiki Aventurica (German)](https://de.wiki-aventurica.de/wiki/Srf%27Srf). They were also worshiped by lizardmen as a good.

If you like sand, maybe some kind of amok running sand golems. But those would miss the absorbing and growing stuff of the replicators. (Unless you count sand)

Comment: Would like to know what caused the down Votes. It may not be the best anwser, but I currently don't think it is incorrect or bad. I'm interrested to improve this. But I need to knwo whats bad.

Comment: Quicksand golems would work pretty well for most parts, but they can't make more of themselves...